# Git LFS cannot download files when switching to a branch

Tags: git, git-lfs

Commited my today's work, switched to another branch and now I'm not able to go back.

```
git checkout feature/499-trophy-after-match

Downloading Content/Blueprints/Game/Royale/BP_Gamemode_Royale_Test.uasset (26 KB)
Error downloading object: Content/Blueprints/Game/Royale/BP_Gamemode_Royale_Test.uasset (cd5cbe0): Smudge error: Error downloading Content/Blueprints/Game/Royale/BP_Gamemode_Royale_Test.uasset (cd5cbe0c9d75fc92257a403ff18539ecd37af2a77bb2defd3a56c12c276d465d): [cd5cbe0c9d75fc92257a403ff18539ecd37af2a77bb2defd3a56c12c276d465d] Object does not exist on the server or you don't have permissions to access it: [404] Object does not exist on the server or you don't have permissions to access it

Errors logged to E:\Projects\UE\Marble-Strike\.git\lfs\logs\20211104T181854.4948673.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.

error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: Content/Blueprints/Game/Royale/BP_Gamemode_Royale_Test.uasset: smudge filter lfs failed
Completed with errors, see above.
```

For some reason, LFS cannot download the file from local cache I guess. Branch is not pushed to origin.
I've tried to revert, rebase, cherry-pick a commit, tried to revert by a single file, tried merge a branch. Nothing helps.

Are the files lost for good? Is there anything I can do to restore my work?

Comment: In git lfs log file there is the same error as line 4 in code block of the topic post:
[404] Object does not exist on the server or you don't have permissions to access it

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? One of my folks is hitting the exact same thing.

Comment: @MatthewClark , Unfortunately no. As far as I remember I had to do my work again in the corrupted file.